# Cant able to deactivate the user and not able to change the user license

Tags: security

Error: This user, as the Automated Case User, must have the "Modify All Data" and "Send Email" permissions. Select a profile or assign a permission set with these permissions enabled.[image]

Comment: Error is self explanatory. Since this is an automated user you have provide mentioned permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, understand about Automated Case User.

**The Automated Case User is the user who is listed in the Case History for all automated case actions in Salesforce -**

- When a case is automatically assigned using assignment rules
- When a case is escalated
- When a case is created online via web to case
- When Email-to-Case fails to create a case, the Automated Case User is
  emailed with the error message(s), of why a case was not created.

This user is also specified in the From address for case escalation email notifications.

**To change the Automated Case User:**

1. In Classic: Click Setup and on the Quick Find box enter 'Support Settings'. In Lightning: Click the Gear icon then Setup and on the Quick Find box enter 'Support Settings'
2. Click Edit to change any of the listed support settings
3. Choose the new Automated Case User by typing their full name in the field or by using the lookup icon
4. Click 'Save'

All automated case actions will now have this new Automated Case User listed on the Case History.

**Note:-**

> Remember: Automated Case user must have the System Administrator
>   profile or the 'Modify All Data' and 'Send Email' permissions.

Now, coming to your question, If you are changing the profile of the automated case user, you need to assign the new profile having the System Administrator profile or the 'Modify All Data' and 'Send Email' permissions.

If you are deactivating it, first change the user assigned as Automated Case User.

**Reference:-**

1. [Details on Automated Case User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326328&type=1&mode=1)
2. [Customize Support Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_supportrules.htm&type=5)